# ls shows file, but nothing else can see it

Tags: bash, github-actions

I'm trying to run a nuget pack and push with a .nuspec file in a GitHub action, but nuget can't seem to find the file.

I've added a `pwd`, an `ls`, and a `cat` to try to debug the issue, but it seems that not even the `cat` can see it.

From my [workflow file](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/blob/master/.github/workflows/publish-schema-langs.yml#L58-L62):

```sh
pwd
ls artifacts/*

NUSPEC_NAME=${{ matrix.nuspec }}
cat artifacts/${NUSPEC_NAME}
```

(I also have a previous run where I echoed `matrix.nuspec`, and it *does* have just the file name `JsonSchema.Net.es.nuspec`.)

[Output](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/runs/5816210023?check_suite_focus=true):

```
/home/runner/work/json-everything/json-everything
JsonSchema.Net.es.nuspec
es
cat: artifacts/JsonSchema.Net.es.nuspec: No such file or directory
```

Maybe I'm crazy, but it seems that since `ls artifacts/*` is outputting

```
JsonSchema.Net.es.nuspec
es
```

(`es` is a folder) then the file `artifacts/JsonSchema.Net.es.nuspec` actually *does* exist.  So why isn't `cat` seeing it?

I've been banging my head against this for a couple hours, and my brain is tired.  Once I figure this out, I think the nuget commands will fall into place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to show everything you have on your system, using the simple command:

```
find . -ls
```

The `-ls` switch will make sure all information is shown, like file type, file or directory, ..., and using that information you might solve your issue.

In case the situation is not clear yet, please edit your question, adding the result of the `find` command.

Comment: Thanks.  Showing everything definitely helped me find my nuspec: I was missing a subfolder in the artifacts download.  Out of curiosity, why does `ls artifacts/*` show my file (makes me feel lied to)?

Comment: So `ls artifacts/*` shows you a file, but it does not show you a subfolder, and the reason for your problem is the absence of that subfolder and is not related to the file, right?

Comment: Yeah, so you're saying that that command will recursively find files, but it displays them without their relative paths?  That doesn't seem very useful.  Regardless, the `find` worked well to discover the file system.